# How to modify a Button Content from a function (c++ UWP app)?

Tags: c++, uwp

Currently learning C++ and using Visual Studio 2017. My UWP app have 10 buttons (named b0-b9) and I want to create a function that will manage the content change of the buttons.

For this I need to pass the button name and the content. I want to modify to the function but I don't know how to do it.

It would look something like this:

```
void contentButtonChange(Button BtnName, String myString) 
{

    BntName->Content = myString;
}

Main() 
{
    .....
    contentButtonChange(b0, string1);
    contentButtonChange(b1, string2);
    contentButtonChange(b2, string3);
    .....
}
```

added note: I'm currently able to change the Content of the button from the Main but I'm unable to write a function that will accept a Button as a parameter. I'm always getting an error no matter what I try.

In the example above BtnName in the function is highlighted with the error: expression must have a pointer or handle type

Comment: This is really off topic, but I see that you're automatically using the C++/CX extensions to use the UWP apis.  However, there's a newer way to access those apis… using C++/WinRT.  It lets you use the std library for a lot of things.  Just an FYI.  Also, no more hats (^)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/index

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it. I need to add this to my function call:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button^ btnName
```

like this:

```
void contentButtonChange(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Button^ btnName, Platform::String^ myString) 
{
    bntName->Content = myString;
}
```

works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextBlock to set to the Button.

```
void contentButtonChange(Button BtnName, string myString) 
{    
    BntName->Content = new TextBlock() { Text = myString };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The thing is that I'm able to change the Content of the button from the main but I'm unable to write a function that will accept a Button as a parameter. I'm always getting an error.

Comment: I tried different things but the code is what you see in my post. The code of the function is what is displayed in my above post.